# Mathematica 1/0 Infinite expression while plotting

Tags: plot, expression, wolfram-mathematica, infinite

```
J = 0.05;
B = 0.02;
Tload[t_] := 0.0;
R1 = 2;
\[Alpha] = 30*\[Pi]/180;
d = 0.05;
g = 0.001;
Nturns = 200;
\[Mu]0 = 4*\[Pi]*10^(-7);
r = 0.03;
lm = 0.02;
d = 0.1;
W = Sqrt[2*r^2 - 2*r^2*Cos[2*a]];
Rgmax = g/(\[Mu]0*r*d);
Rm = lm/(\[Mu]0*W*d);
square[x_, x1_, x2_] := UnitStep[x - x1]*(1 - UnitStep[x - x2])
Rg[\[Theta]_] := 
 Rgmax/((2 \[Alpha] - Mod[\[Theta][t], \[Pi]])*
     square[Mod[\[Theta][t], \[Pi]], -2 \[Alpha], 
      2 \[Alpha]] + (2 \[Alpha] - Mod[-\[Theta][t], \[Pi]])*
     square[Mod[-\[Theta][t], \[Pi]], -2 \[Alpha], 2 \[Alpha]])
L[\[Theta]_] := 
 Nturns^2/(
  2*Rg[\[Theta]] + 
   Rm) *(square[Mod[\[Theta][t], \[Pi]], -2 \[Alpha], 2 \[Alpha]] + 
    square[Mod[-\[Theta][t], \[Pi]], -2 \[Alpha], 2 \[Alpha]])
Plot[L[\[Theta]], {\[Theta][t], -8 \[Alpha], 8 \[Alpha]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I'm sorry but I could not paste as mathematica can show (newbie here). However, I tried several solutions to get rid of 1/0 inf expression of L[theta] but I didn't get it.

Please, copy and paste it to a notebook and run it.

I multiply L[theta] with my square function to make undefined areas equal to zero(f.e 2a, Pi-2a should be zero as other intervals) but it did not work.

How can I identify this function properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have zero denominators in your Rg[]. Rg[\\[Theta]_] := (denom = ((2 \\[Alpha] - Mod[\\[Theta], \\[Pi]])* square[Mod[\\[Theta], \\[Pi]], -2 \\[Alpha], 2 \\[Alpha]] + (2 \\[Alpha] - Mod[-\\[Theta], \\[Pi]])* square[Mod[-\\[Theta], \\[Pi]], -2 \\[Alpha], 2 \\[Alpha]]); If[denom == 0, Print["Zero denom" ]; 1, denom]);  I have also changed your \\[Theta][t] to \\[Theta] everywhere in your code to be more normal.

Comment: Theta[t] is variable that will put in differential equations to solve with NDSolve function,at this stage does not matter it is depend t or not. However, Rg[theta] has zero in it i know it should be also. Please try to plot 1/Rg[theta] there is no 1/0 expressions. If you try to solve or plot 1/(Rg[theta]+Rm which is also in the definition of L[theta] it gives undefined 1/0 intervals :(

Comment: whats `a`? my guess you changed from `a` to `alpha` and missed one.. you could use `UnitBox` by the way, though i don't think that relates to your error

Comment: Yes, sorry a is alpha but as you said my error directly relates to Rm located in denominator. Rg has 0 in it but when plotted 1/Rg there is no error. I dont get it :(

Comment: Any of them solved this ?

Comment: You might want to ask the question on **the [mathematica.se] site** instead. The Mathematica experts are there.

Comment: I just fixed `a` to `alpha` in the definition of `W` and it works fine.  Be sure to restart the kernel if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
J=0.05; B=0.02; Tload[t_]:=0.0; R1=2; \[Alpha]=30*\[Pi]/180; d=0.05;
g=0.001; Nturns=200; \[Mu]0=4*\[Pi]*10^-7; r=0.03; lm=0.02; d=0.1;
W=Sqrt[2*r^2-2*r^2*Cos[2*\[Alpha]]]; Rgmax=g/(\[Mu]0*r*d); Rm=lm/(\[Mu]0*W*d);
square[x_, x1_, x2_]:=UnitStep[x-x1]*(1-UnitStep[x-x2]);
Rg[\[Theta]_]:=Rgmax/((2 \[Alpha]-Mod[\[Theta],\[Pi]])*square[Mod[\[Theta],
  \[Pi]],-2 \[Alpha], 2 \[Alpha]] +(2 \[Alpha]-Mod[-\[Theta],\[Pi]])*
  square[Mod[-\[Theta],\[Pi]],-2 \[Alpha], 2 \[Alpha]]);
L[\[Theta]_] := Nturns^2/(2*Rg[\[Theta]]+Rm)*(square[Mod[\[Theta],\[Pi]],
  -2 \[Alpha],2 \[Alpha]]+square[Mod[-\[Theta],\[Pi]],-2 \[Alpha], 2 \[Alpha]]);

Plot[L[\[Theta]], {\[Theta],-8 \[Alpha],8 \[Alpha]}, PlotRange->All, PlotPoints->200]
```

[image: The plot]

All I did was fix your a versus Alpha and your Theta[t] versus Theta confusion.

Theta is a variable and Theta[t] is a function. There is a complicated explanation of this, but those are not necessarily the same thing and may mean very different things to Mathematica. The further you stray from the very conventional way of doing things in Mathematica the more confusing holes you can fall into with no way of understanding why it isn't doing what you expect it to.